# closed, convex cone C $\in \mathbb{R}^n$ whose linear hull is the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-cone

I am trying to construct the following example:

let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$ be symmetric matrix and C $\in \mathbb{R^n}$ a closed, convex cone whose linear hull is the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$ and

$x^TAx >0 \ \forall x \in C \backslash \{0\} $,

but $A$ not positive semi-definite.

---

I constructed $A$ as follows:

$ A = \left( \begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0  \\ 
0 & 1\\ 
\end{array} \right)$,
such that $x^T A x = x_1^2 + x_2^2 > 0 $

I am completely stuck on constructing a cone that will fullfill above conditions. Any input is highly appretiated.

Comment: Problem: your $A$ is positive (semi-)definite. Try$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$ instead, i.e. reflection in the $y$ axis. Can you think of a cone $C$ with non-empty interior where $v \in C$ forms an acute angle with $Av$?

Comment: but, this maxtrix $A$ is not symmetric? So maybe $A = \left (\begin{array}{rrr} 
-1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 \\ 

\end{array} \right)$ instead? Nvm, that doesn't work either, because it would never be pos. def. in $C$ then.

Comment: It is symmetric, since $A^\top = A$. Remember, the transpose reflects along the main diagonal.

Comment: sorry, completely missed that

Comment: ok, so if $A = \left( \begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0  \\ 
0 & -1 \\  
\end{array} \right)$, then $x^TAx = x_1^2 - x_2^2 <0 \ \forall |x_2| > |x_1|.$ So, if I choose the set $|x_1| < |x_2|$ then the interior forms a non-empty, closed, convex cone. $A$ will be positiv definit on this set, but not on the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, except you've chosen a (non-convex) double cone. Just choose $x_2 > |x_1|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and let $C = \{ (x \mid \alpha x_1 \ge  |x_2| \}$.
Let $A = \operatorname{diag} (1,-1)$. Then if $x \in C\setminus \{0\}$ we have
$x^TAx =x_1^2-x_2^2 \ge  (1-\alpha^2) x_1^2+ \alpha x_1^2-x_2^2 \ge (1-\alpha^2) x_1^2 > 0$. It should be clear that since $(1,\pm \alpha) \in C$ that the span of $C$ is the entire plane.